Solana NFT Collection using Metaplex Candy Machine v3 and sugar
for the past 7 months I am trying to deploy an NFT collection on Solana blockchain using Metaplex Candy Machine V3 and sugar, but nothing is compatible, I keep running on issue after issue and the only explanation I get from Metaplex team is that nothing is compatible. I'm so lost and would appreciate if someone can help me.

As mentioned in discord you are using incompatible versions, correct. There are multiple options that you have that i mentioned before, too:

Use the latest sugar version using on of the unofficial UIs like this one.
Build your own Mint UI. You can find more information on this in the developer hub
Use an older sugar version that is compatible to the UI you are trying to use. Since you are trying to use a candy machine v2 UI you would need sugar  v1.1.0. When installing sugar through the recommended script it asks you which version you want to use.
Instead of Sugar use a Launchpad like Truffle. Those allow creators to create their NFT Collections without coding knowledge.

Feel Free to ask more questions here, or on the Metaplex discord where you are already active.
